# Include string into another string using regex

Tags: regex, go

I have some set of strings. Strings might have items listed between square brackets. I'd like to include into strings with brackets a constant number of extra items. Brackets might be empty, or absent. For example:

- string1  --> string1 # added nothing
- string2[] --> string2[extra1="1",extra2="2"] # added two items
- string3[item="1"] --> string3[item="1",extra1="1",extra2="2"] # added two items

Currently I achieve this with the following code (Golang):

```
str1 := "test"
str2 := `test[]`
str3 := `test[item1="1"]`
    
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\[(.+)?\]`)

for _, s := range []string{str1, str2, str3} {
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, fmt.Sprintf(`[item1="a",item2="b",$1]`))
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

But in the output, in case of empty brackets I also got an unwanted comma "," in the end:

```
test
test[item1="a",item2="b",]
test[item1="a",item2="b",item1="1"]
```

Is it possible to avoid paste comma in case of empty brackets?

Of course it's possible to parse string again and trim the comma, but it seems suboptimal.

[Code example on Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U-KBAHpK4uI)

Answer (score 1):

> You can have two regexes, where one matches for empty [] and other
> matches for string with text inside []. Below is the tested code -
> https://play.golang.org/p/_DOOGDMUOCm
>
> Second way is just look back in the string after replacing it. If the
> last two characters are ,] and you can substring till , and add ]. I
> guess you already know this approach.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str1 := "test"
    str2 := `test[]`
    str3 := `test[item1="1"]`
    
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\[(.*)\]`)

    for _, s := range []string{str1, str2, str3} {
       matched,err := regexp.Match(`\[(.+)\]`, []byte(s));
       _ = err;
       if(matched==true){
          s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, fmt.Sprintf(`[item1="a",item2="b",$1]`));
       }else {
          s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, fmt.Sprintf(`[item1="a",item2="b"]`));
       }
       fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```